# How Can I check events on AWS EFS using python code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I am trying with AWS EFS in multiple accounts. I need to know if the tag value of EFS got changed to some other values in all accounts from a centralized account using python code. How can I implement this event based triggering?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? For example, is this a one-off activity, or you wish to do it on an on-going basis? Are you asking how to write a system that will be notified whenever a tag value on an EFS filesystem changes? This sounds like it might be a good use-case for AWS Config.

Comment: I have to take the backup of EFS on daily basis, based on the Tags set. if tag is set to back=true, i need to include the file system, and the tag can be set to false if needed. so I need to get to know if the tag value set to false with out checking the value manually. So I need to create an event based on the tag change. And I would need to get it triggered from a centralized account. Based on this, I need to trigger the lambda function for back up

Comment: You can create an Amazon CloudWatch Event on an API call that is detected by AWS CloudTrail. Do you know which API call would be used to change the tag? One way to find this would be to do it via the console, then wait a few minutes and look at the CloudTrail to view the API call that changed the tag. You can then use CloudWatch Events to trigger on such a call. Then, it would be a matter of figuring out how to do it centrally (but one step at a time).

Comment: Thanks John for your suggestions. I got it working by creating an event  for tag change and role in the account account and gave the permission to centralized account role to read from the events.